# Multinational Online Course/Training/Group for Mothers and Infant Activities

Tags: infant

In current situation while being locked in home the most of the time and with no access to pediatrician I am looking for online events/course/training where my wife will be able to exercise baby along other mothers or have similar events/activities. Is there anything like that? I need it to be applicable to Bulgaria.

The aim is to have some movement exercises or other activities connected to playing.

Comment: It's really unclear what you are asking for. Online group/gym for mothers with their babies? Why would that be restricted to (or "applicable to") any specific region? Though time zones could be a problem if you find something on another continent.

Comment: @tripleee,yes, online/gym group, but concentrated on baby movements/development. I saw some groups that are localized to UK for example, couldn't find an option that is multinational. I guess it's a matter of finding one, but my google search didn't lead me anywhere.

Comment: Are you talking about programs like PEKiP?

Comment: @Stephie, yes, but looking for an online option and one I can access from another country, for this one I can't get to such option from what I see.